# Determining length using scale factor

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

I came across a question (as shown below) and I'm confused on what the answer is. Are they saying length is 12cm or is there a way to find out the other sides length as well?

[image: Mary's backyard]

```
Determine the actual length of Mary's backyard in metres.
```

Here's my attempt at trying to answer this question, but I'm unsure if its correct or not.

$$ \frac{12}{x} = \frac{1}{150} $$
$$ x = 12 * 150 = 1800 cm $$

Any ideas?

Comment: If you have been told that the length in a $1:150$ scale diagram is $12$ cm, then your calculation is correct, except that you are supposed to give the answer in metres. If you have been told nothing else, one cannot determine the width.

Answer (score 3):

*Suggestion*: do not rely on formulae too much, they are no substitute for *understanding* what the problem means.

*Hint*: where the diagram says "scale $1:150$" it means $1$ unit on the diagram corresponds to $150$ units in real life.  So, $1$cm on the diagram corresponds to $150$cm in real life, and $12$cm on the diagram corresponds to. . . ?

Comment: So then 1800cm is the answer?

Comment: Yes, but see comment from @André Nicolas above.